# Best Approach to get & send data from server in Android

Tags: java, android, http

Hi i am a iPhone developer and new to android. I want to know a best approach in android to make a http connection and get the response from server and (like iOS there are connectionDidFinish, connectionDidFail methods) i want to show a loader when connection is start and when connection is complete then i dismiss the loader. how to do that.

I read about HttpConnection, HttpURLConnection, DefaultHttpClient but i am too confuse that which is best approach and how to use them and one more thing connection is like a asynchronous connection.

one more thing i want to make two or more connection so that i have to differentiate between them also so suggest me that also?

Answer (score 1):

To show and dismiss loader (i.e. ProgressBar or ProgressDialog), implement [**AsyncTask**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which is known as [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) in Android.

Comment: can you give me a simple tutorial for this so that i can easily implement that and one more thing that i forget to told you is that i want also too make 2 or more connection so i have to differentiate them also.